# E convergence set in $C^n$ for example

Tags: education

Definition. A subset E of  $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ is said to be a convergence set in  $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ if $E=Conv(f)$ for some divergent series f of Class $(1,0)$. what is for example $E$?

Comment: Ayush Jaiswal thank you.I didn't know good.